# jQuery ajax Script Creating Random Tables

Tags: php, jquery, instagram

Has anyone got any ideas regarding this problem? Surely there's someone out there who's had experience using the instagram API?

I'm trying to use the script featured on this website:http://stuffthatspins.com/stuff/instagram-user-stream-display/

It allows you to display a stream of your Instagram photos on your website, but when the script runs it fails to display the stream.

I've registered the app in the Instagram API developer section, and have obtained my user id and a valid access token, so I think it's the code or how I'm implementing it thats the issue.

When I take a peek using Google Chrome's dev tools I get an error on the line with the url:

```
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<?=$user_id?>/media/recent/?access_token=accesstokenhere/',
```

And under the elements tab there are a lot of html table elements that don't appear in the example page by the scripts author.

Here's the code:

```
    <?
    $user_id = "validUserID"; 
    $num_to_display = "20";
    ?>

    <style>
    .instagram-placeholder {
    float: left;
    }
    </style>

    <h1>jQuery Instagram User Stream Display Really Easy with a json call</h1>
    uses jQuery and json to get an instagram user feed and display it on your site.
    <br/>
    Source and idea from <a href="https://forrst.com/posts/Using_the_Instagram_API-ti5">forrst</a>
    <br/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">      </script>
    <div class="instagram"></div>

    <script>

    // small = + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +
    // resolution: low_resolution, thumbnail, standard_resolution

    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false,
            url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<?=$user_id?>/media/recent/?access_token=validToken",
            success: function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < <?=$num_to_display?>; i++) {
            $(".instagram").append("<div class='instagram-placeholder'><a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link +"'><img class='instagram-image' src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +"' /></a></div>");   
                }     

            }
        });
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: what do you get if you put that url in a browser? do you get your JSON data?

Comment: The stuffthatspins.com url? It runs and I get the stream of Instagram photos.

Comment: No, I mean this url `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<?=$user_id?>/media/recent/?access_token=validToken`

Comment: Ah right yeah, when I replace the <?$user_id?> with user id and the validToken part with the token I get a page that has a lot of plain text code on it.

Comment: Have you tried testing out the call from here? http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/

Comment: Thanks for the help @wirey I appreciate it, when you say test out the call you mean the whole script part? (sorry for the questions I'm very new to jQuery)

Comment: I tried just the URL and the GET parameter and I get "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" and lots of other code.